# How can I call this HelloWorld web method with plain JavaScript/Ajax, without using JSON or anything?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I hate to be posting a question like this on here, but I'm running out of options for really understanding how this works.  In a normal .Net web service, without being configured for JSON or anything, there is the following web method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal str As Int32) As String
    Return "Hello, World!  str=" & str
End Function
```

I would like to make a really simple webpage that would just use JS to call this web method, get the value out of it, and print it in an alert() statement.  I'm continuing to research the subject on my own, but I am having a very hard time finding a straight answer to this question.

This is about the closest I've been able to come (aside from this not actually using the return value):

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
        alert("spam");                                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "&str=1",
            url: "<HTTP path and filename>.asmx/HelloWorld",
            timeout: 15000,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("good");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("bad");
            }
        });
        alert("spam");
    //-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again I don't like posting a question like this on StackOverflow, but I've been unable to find a **clear, straight** answer to this, and I'm very new with JavaScript.  Thanks!

EDIT: Throwing a try...catch block around the Ajax call, I get the following message:

```
$ is not defined
```

Comment: You don't need to put &str. You can just leave data as an object and the jquery method will handle it for you. When you POST something the data doesn't get appended to the URL. When you use GET your data will get appended to the url. If you use something like Fiddler or firebug you can see exactly how the request is formed. In this instance I believe your variable will be received as `&str`. Start out here for the diff between GET/POST: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started then read the ajax doc for jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a variable. Your code shows that it's using the jQuery library, using `$` as an alias.

You have to include the jQuery library if you want to use this code.

To do so, include this before your code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, if you're new to javascript, I recommend you first try without jQuery.

For a great tutorial, I can only show you the best resource I know: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

If you absolutely want to use jQuery, you have to know that your `data` parameter is wrong. It does accept a string, but this string isn't well-formed, it should be this: `str=1`. Adding another variable would be `str=1&foo=2`.

jQuery allows you to put an object instead of a string, this provides some syntactic sugar and is generally the recommended way to go (less error-prone):

```
data: {
    str: 1,
    foo: 2
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  And how would I use the data parameter in the success function?

Comment: @Panzercrisis You don't. Why would you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the return value out of the web method and print it to the screen.  I was hoping I could just put alert(data) inside the success function, but that doesn't seem to be working too well.

Comment: It's printing [object XMLDocument] to the screen, which kind of surprises me.  I thought it was just gonna be a regular string.  How do I get "Hello, World!  str=" & str out of there?

Comment: "syntastic sugar" sounds fantastic, where can I get some?

Comment: @TheZ Meh, typo :p (plus, I confused with [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).)

Comment: @Panzercrisis Use `console.log` instead of `alert`. It spits out more meaningful information, such as what's in the variable. You have to open the console to see the result.