# Consume Web Service Method From HTML5 using Javascript

Tags: html

I am developing my first HTML 5 application which has to read data from a web service.
Can anybody tell me how I can call a web method from HTML 5 using JavaScript ?

Comment: Are you talking about AJAX web services? Then google for `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX call to an ASP.NET WebMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770679/jquery-ajax-call-to-an-asp-net-webmethod)

Comment: @Philipp - Thanks for your reply.This worked well in IE but it's not working in Mozilla. And I am getting error at  xmlHttpReq.send() method. My Code snippets is    `code`var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttpReq.open("POST", "http://Localhost/EventWebService/Service.asmx/Add", false);
                xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHttpReq.send("num1=12&num2=13");
                alert(xmlHttpReq.responseText);`code`

Answer (score 0):

In this question you have an answer what should you put in order to call a web method in HTML.

[How can I call this HelloWorld web method with plain JavaScript/Ajax, without using JSON or anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128736/how-can-i-call-this-helloworld-web-method-with-plain-javascript-ajax-without-us)

It is using ajax, but it should give you an example. Also take a look at the answer